# Java JBDI how to get the affected rows and generated id with a query on duplicate key update mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I'm trying to find out how to return affected rows on an insert and also get the generated key `id` from the same query;

I have this query

```
@SqlUpdate("""
            INSERT INTO table_name (
                account, 
                state,
                lock,
                external_id
)
            VALUES (
                :account,
                :state,
                :lock,
                :external_id)
            """)
    @GetGeneratedKeys("id")
    Long insert(@BindBean ExampleBean exampleBean);
```

That I want to update to something like this for an upsert so when I find a duplicate entry I would like to update it to something like this

```
  @SqlUpdate("""
            INSERT INTO table_name (
                account, 
                state,
                lock,
                external_id
)
            VALUES (
                :account,
                :state,
                :lock,
                :external_id)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY
                UPDATE
                external_id = :external_id
                lock = :lock
            """)
    @GetGeneratedKeys("id")
    idRows insert(@BindBean ExampleBean exampleBean);  

 public record idRows(Long id, int rowsAffected) {}
```

called by doing

```
try (Handle handle = jdbi.open()) {
        return handle.attach(ExampleBean.class).upsert(exampleBean));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(example);
            return null;
        }
```

on my Hikari Datasource I have set `"useAffectedRows", true`

where I can map both the affected rows and the generated ID at the same time to my record, any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: `upsert` is a term introduced by Couchbase. On relational databases you need to distinguish insert and update. Thus I believe both your SqlUpdate statements are wrongly showing "insert into ..."

Comment: Hey @queeg,  Query 1 is what I want to turn into the style of query 2, which is why I am using on duplicate key update which mirrors the behavior of an upsert but perhaps I have worded the question wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SqlUpdate("""
    INSERT INTO table_name (
        account, 
        state,
        lock,
        external_id
    )
    VALUES (
        :account,
        :state,
        :lock,
        :external_id)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        external_id = :external_id,
        lock = :lock
""")
@GetGeneratedKeys({"id", "rowsAffected"})
idRows upsert(@BindBean ExampleBean exampleBean);
```

###### Your idRows record should look like this:

```
public record idRows(Long id, int rowsAffected) {}
```

This way, when you call the upsert method, it should return an instance of idRows with both the generated ID and the number of affected rows.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, My first issue was that it needed a row mapper so I've added one 
```class idRowsMapper implements RowMapper<idRows> {
        @Override
        public idRows map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
            return new idRows(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getInt("rowsAffected"));
        }
    }
```


`rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()`
 only returns one and at that column name the only one I can see is `GENERATED_KEY` which gives me the generated key and not the affected rows I'm also looking for